# MySql — SELECT. Как дублировать запись в соответствии с количеством вхождений подстроки в ячейку?

Tags: mysql, select

есть таблица с колонкой colors, в которой хранится JSON

```
--------------------------------------
id    |   colors
1     |   {{cid: 1},{cid: 2}}
2     |   {{cid: 1},{cid: 2},{cid: 3}}
--------------------------------------
```

можно ли построить запрос так, чтобы запись дублировалась столько раз, сколько вхождений cid есть в колонке colors?
и получалось:

```
--------------------------------------
id    |   colors
1     |   {{cid: 1},{cid: 2}}
1     |   {{cid: 1},{cid: 2}}
2     |   {{cid: 1},{cid: 2},{cid: 3}}
2     |   {{cid: 1},{cid: 2},{cid: 3}}
2     |   {{cid: 1},{cid: 2},{cid: 3}}
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: Максимально возможное количество cid в одной записи - ограничено? Версия MySQL - какая точно? *можно ли построить запрос* Да, можно.

Comment: максимально - не ограничено, по факту до 30 будет встречаться. версия 5.5.41

Comment: Для указанной версии либо придётся генерировать динамически таблицу чисел (причём с максимумом гарантированно не меньше количества элементов в записи), либо реализовывать решение в формате хранимой процедуры с временной таблицей.